# Zooming class added to all images in slider without checking if the 'li' is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider, elevatezoom

I have a problem with flexslider 2 and elevate zoom plus.
I would like to zoom active image from the slider. I have to use this option, because I also use ACF in wordpress and only this one works as I want. Unfortunately code which I created doesn't work as it should

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.flexslider .slides > li').hasClass('flex-active-slide')) {
    $('.flexslider .slides li img').addClass('zooming');
}
else
{
    $('.flexslider .slides li img').removeClass('zooming');
}
});
</script>
```

When the `li` has class which means that image is active, then I would like to add class to the image which has to be zoomed. Unfortunately it adds zooming class to all images in slider without checking if the `li` is active. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to add different js for this, you can add in initialization only like below:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
       animation: "slide",
       start: function (slider) {
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
          $(slider).find(".flex-active-slide img").addClass("zooming"); // this will add class on slider start
       },
       before: function (slider) {
          $(slider).find(".zooming").each(function () {
              $(this).removeClass("zooming"); // this will remove class from previous tag
          });
       },
       after: function (slider) {
          $(slider).find(".flex-active-slide img").addClass("zooming"); // this will add class in next tag
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Ok, it seems, to be working, but I had to change `$(window).load(function () ` to `$(document).ready(function () ` . because it was not loading . Classes are assign correctly, but zoom doesn't work now. Zooming code: `<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".zooming").ezPlus({
    zoomType: 'inner',
    cursor: 'crosshair'
  });
});
</script>`

Comment: Have you included js after or before jquery.min?

Comment: I included js library before plugin libraries

Comment: Try adding (."zooming").ezPlus function in the start function and after function as well. It worked for me in flex slider demo html

Comment: Worked !! Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is close, but you are targeting all images with this line:
`$('.flexslider .slides li img').addClass('zooming');`

It also has to run every time the classes of the `slide > li` changes.

Unfortunately jQuery doesn't have something nice like `.classChange()`, but [here](https://gist.github.com/kozachenko/30e55fb5f9ae170eedfe258430fd09ec) is a function - created by kozachenko on github - which does what we want.

So you can add kozachenko's function and then use it to see if the class of the `li` has changed, then add/remove your `zooming` class.

To find only the one you're looking for, you can use the active class as a selector, and then use jQuery.find() to look for the image inside of that particular element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //kozachenko's function https://gist.github.com/kozachenko/30e55fb5f9ae170eedfe258430fd09ec
  (function(){//adds a trigger step to the addClass/removeClass jQuery functions
    var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass;
    var originalRemoveClassMethod = jQuery.fn.removeClass;
    jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
        var result = originalAddClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );
        jQuery(this).trigger('classChanged');
        return result;
    }
    jQuery.fn.removeClass = function(){
        var result = originalRemoveClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );
        jQuery(this).trigger('classChanged');
        return result;
    }
  })();

  $('.flexslider .slides > li').on('classChanged', function(){//the new event triggered by addClass()/removeClass()
    $(this).find('img').removeClass('zooming');//first remove the class from any other image
    $('.flex-active-slide').find('img').addClass('zooming'); //add the class to active image
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. It doesn't add a class to image.

Comment: Have you added this code after your
```$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });

Comment: Yes, I did. I would insert whole code here but i don't know how to do this